# unable to login using google after changing the package name

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, google-signin

i used "change_app_package_name" to change my package name , and then i had run the command "flutterfire configure" to setup the app in google console for the updated package name, and added the "sha keys". and when i tried to login it is not working.

before changing the package name it was working perfect.

```
here are some lines of error for reference :-
I/PlayCore(14586): UID: [10159]  PID: [14586] AppUpdateService : requestUpdateInfo(com.aks.khati_hangout_app)
I/PlayCore(14586): UID: [10159]  PID: [14586] AppUpdateService : Initiate binding to the service.
I/flutter (14586): PlatformException - sign_in_failed: com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: 
I/PlayCore(14586): UID: [10159]  PID: [14586] AppUpdateService : ServiceConnectionImpl.onServiceConnected(ComponentInfo{com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.installservice.DevTriggeredUpdateService})
I/PlayCore(14586): UID: [10159]  PID: [14586] AppUpdateService : linkToDeath
I/PlayCore(14586): UID: [10159]  PID: [14586] OnRequestInstallCallback : onRequestInfo
I/PlayCore(14586): UID: [10159]  PID: [14586] AppUpdateService : Unbind from service.
```

i updated the sha key but unable to login

Comment: I've gotten this error plenty of times, it's usually a problem with Google Cloud / Firebase. You have to update your SHA keys there.

Comment: updated but not working

Comment: You mentioned you changed the package name. In that case a new app with the new package name should be reflected in the Firebase project. Now add the SHA keys there. Not to your old app